# Onclick is not calling in kitkat(4.4.4) version in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed an android app. When click on Imageview on tool bar, QR scan will be opened.

I have tested in Naught(7.0) and marshmallow. It worked fine. But in kitkat verison 4.4.4, when click on Image view, onclick method is not calling.

Why it is happening like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

In gradle file, I have given like this.

```
minsdkversion -15
Maxsdkversion - 26
```

Defined toolbar like this

```
mContext = (VilanApplication) getApplicationContext();
setContentView(R.layout.qr_app_bar);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_QR);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
listOfImages = new ArrayList<String>();
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
toolbar.setTitle("SEL");
```

And this is onclicklistener for imageview.

```
Inout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Inout_Main_Scan == 1){
                    Inout_Main_Scan = 2;
                    RemainAuditAsseetInfoTask RTask = new 
RemainAuditAsseetInfoTask();                     
RTask.setContextandActivity(mContext,Main_Activity.this,
AreaName.getText().toString());
                    RTask.execute();
                    AreaName.setText("");
                    btn_Scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Inout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Area Scan Ended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Area Scan Starts with Long Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

[image: When click on that Image, onclick listener not calling in kitkat]

Comment: Are you extending `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`? You should use `AppCompatActivity` if not using and try again

Comment: If **Inout** is view from option menu you should handle click with **onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)**. I strongly recommend running app in debug mode, so you can clearly see what is problem.

Comment: Try `android:clickable="true"` in your ImageView

Comment: I have tried all above 3 but it's not working...

Comment: If InOut button is in the toolbar then you must use onOptionItemSelected() method with onCreateMenu()